# how to append vectors element by element?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, data.table

I have to produce a CSV file in a sort of pre-defined format. The input data is like this:

```
> set.seed(1234)
> indata <- data.frame(id = sample(seq(1, 50, 1), 3),
                     ref = c("ref1", "ref2", "ref3"))

> indata 
  id  ref
1 33 ref1
2  1 ref2
3 12 ref3
```

The output that needs to be generated:

```
> outdata <- data.frame(`line#` = rep(c(1,2), nrow(indata), replace = TRUE),
                      `Prod Date`= rep(c(as.Date(Sys.Date(), format = "%d.%m.%Y"), ""), nrow(indata) , replace = TRUE),
                       `Prod Ref` = c("ref1", "", "ref2", "", "ref3", ""))
> outdata
  line.  Prod.Date Prod.Ref
1     1 2019-09-26     ref1
2     2       <NA>         
3     1 2019-09-26     ref2
4     2       <NA>         
5     1 2019-09-26     ref3
6     2       <NA>
```

The problem is, generating the last column based on `indata$ref`.

It might be a very simple thing to do but it's not occuring to me right now, how to do this elegantly.

Basically what I want to do is, leaving one empty row after each 'ref'.

I'd like to produce the 'ref' column already at the data.frame creation stage. Any elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create a vector by `rbind`ing `indata$ref` with any empty value

```
c(rbind(indata$ref, ""))
#[1] "ref1" ""     "ref2" ""     "ref3" ""
```

So your `data.frame` call would look like :

```
data.frame(`line#` = rep(c(1,2), nrow(indata), replace = TRUE),
           `Prod Date`= rep(c(as.Date(Sys.Date(), format = "%d.%m.%Y"), ""), 
                         nrow(indata) , replace = TRUE),
       `Prod Ref` = c(rbind(indata$ref, "")))

#  line.  Prod.Date Prod.Ref
#1     1 2019-09-26     ref1
#2     2       <NA>         
#3     1 2019-09-26     ref2
#4     2       <NA>         
#5     1 2019-09-26     ref3
#6     2       <NA>
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
indata <- data.frame(id = sample(seq(1, 50, 1), 3),
                   ref = c("ref1", "ref2", "ref3"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse` to create the columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
indata %>% 
      select(ref) %>% 
      uncount(2) %>% 
      mutate(Prod.Date = Sys.Date(), line. = rowid(ref)) %>% 
      mutate(Prod.Date = replace(Prod.Date, line.==2, NA), 
             ref = replace(as.character(ref), line. == 2, '')) %>% 
             select(line., Prod.Date, Prod.ref = ref)
#  line.  Prod.Date Prod.ref
#1     1 2019-09-26     ref1
#2     2       <NA>         
#3     1 2019-09-26     ref2
#4     2       <NA>         
#5     1 2019-09-26     ref3
#6     2       <NA>
```